# Getting my output as undefined. Can anyone help me with it..?

Tags: javascript

Function that takes in a positive parameter num and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of times that must multiply the digits in num until it reach a single digit.

```js
var persistenceCount = 0;

function persistence(num) {
  var arr = _parseToNumericArray(num);
  if (_checkLength(arr)) {
    return persistenceCount;
  } else {
    persistenceCount++;
    var newNum = _getMultiple(arr);
    persistence(newNum);
  }

}

function _parseToNumericArray(num) {
  var n = num.toString().split("");
  return n.map(function(elem) {
    return parseInt(elem);
  });
}

function _checkLength(arr) {
  return arr.length === 1;
}

function _getMultiple(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a * b;
  });
}

console.log(persistence(39)); // Getting output as undefined
```

Comment: In your else part you forgot to return..  `return persistence(newNum);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like **@Keith** said, you forgot to return the value.

```js
var persistenceCount = 0;

function persistence(num) {
  var arr = _parseToNumericArray(num);
  if (_checkLength(arr)) {
    return persistenceCount;
  } else {
    persistenceCount++;
    var newNum = _getMultiple(arr);
    return persistence(newNum);
  }
}

function _parseToNumericArray(num) {
  var n = num.toString().split("");
  return n.map(function(elem) {
    return parseInt(elem);
  });
}

function _checkLength(arr) {
  return arr.length === 1;
}

function _getMultiple(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a * b;
  });
}

console.log(persistence(39)); // Outputs 3
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no return statement in the else. So return undefined.

By default, in JavaScript, a function always return undefined if nothing is returned.

Comment: oops, my bad. Thanks for the guidance @MathRobin